# How to assign an outer scoped variable from within an anonymous function being used as a param in JS?

Tags: javascript, scope

(Couldn't think of any simpler way to write the title for this, but the code should explain it).

Here's my code:

```
function logIn(email, password) {
   var response;
   Parse.User.logIn(email, password, {
     success: function(user) {
       response = [true, user];
     },
     error: function(user, error) {
       response = [false, "Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message];
     }
   });
   return response; // still undefined :(
}
```

How can I correctly return `response` for this function so that it's defined? Just putting `return response` within the success: and error: callbacks doesn't return the outer logIn() function obviously, so I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: Global `vars` - The high-fructose corn syrup of programming.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: This could be scoped within another function, for all we know!

Comment: @Eric - For all we know Mike is the missing link or the alien lifeforce. When speculating, speculate BIG.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, the full file is here: https://github.com/mikecrittenden/baconflow/blob/master/js/services.js#L10 ...it's an AngularJS service using Parse.com's JavaScript SDK as the backend.

Comment: Repost of comment on @Eric's answer: Mike -  See [with async (non-blocking)](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YCecC/2/) and [with sync (blocking)](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YCecC/5/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert(response);
```

is executing before

```
response = ...
```

because your `Parse.User.logIn` function does not run it's callback immediately. If it did, then you wouldn't have a problem.

```
function logIn(email, password, callback) {
   Parse.User.logIn(email, password, {
     success: function(user) {
       callback([true, user]);
     },
     error: function(user, error) {
       callback([false, "Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message]);
     }
   });
}

logIn(..., ..., function(response) {

});
```

At this point though, it becomes questionable if the function servers any purpose. Having separate functions for error and success is probably better.

Comment: Thanks. However, the problem I'm having is I need to return `response` and doing so from within the callback doesn't return the outer function. I edited my question to be a little clearer. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeCrittenden - You're still going to have the same problem. It's a race condition and `response` doesn't have a chance. EDIT: Although, I suppose you could go SYNCHRONOUS on it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish So there's absolutely no way to return the response from my outer logIn() function? I just need to be able to do something like `result = logIn(email, password)` to determine if the login was successful or not.

Comment: @MikeCrittenden - Not really; you have to work with it, which means either async and callbacks triggered by a response, or synchronously waiting. Since it's a login, conceivably locking the browser isn't "so bad". But you literally cannot get a response the way it's designed using asynchronous methods. It's not possible.

Comment: @MikeCrittenden - See [with async (non-blocking)](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YCecC/2/) and [with sync (blocking)](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YCecC/5/).